# Responsive Ribbon Navigation

Tags: css, navigation, icons, overflow, responsive

I am working on a responsive ribbon navigation bar, that I created using ionicons (http://ionicons.com).

Everything looks great! The only problem is when I resize the browser to a smaller size the right part of the ribbon is causing scrollbars to appear. You can see what I'm working on here: https://jsfiddle.net/gyrndofr/

I tried to use `overflow-x:hidden`, but then everything except the navigation bar disappears. To see the `overflow-x:hidden` just uncomment `line 7` in the fiddle css.

I'm trying to keep the functionality, but just hide the overflow, which is why I tried `overflow-x:hidden`, but maybe I'm just adding that to the wrong element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a closer look and made some adjustments, hopefully this helps someone else :-)

https://jsfiddle.net/66fwcz71/

Basically, I applied a max-width to both the `#nav` container and the `#nav ul`, the trick is...instead of having a `#nav:before` - `#nav:after` and a `#nav ul:before` - `#nav ul:after` both, the shadow and the ribbon have to be part of the `ul`, so I left the ribbon as the `#nav:before` - `#nav:after`, then created a `.left` and `.right` div with my shadow...that way the ribbon is the `#nav` element and the `.left` - `.right` is the shadow.

Thanks,
Josh